# Stream a payload to S3 in NodeJs

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3, stream

I need to stream a payload to s3. I know it is possible with a file, but I'm not sure I can do this with a body that I get in a request.

This is my code:

```
const {
  body;
} = req;

const {
  bucket: Bucket;
} = customer;

const Key = `${process.env.IMPORTS_PATH}/${idImport}.json`;
const s3 = Amazon.s3(access, secret);

const params = {
  Bucket,
  Key,
  Body: Buffer.from(JSON.stringify(body)),
};

const s3Upload = await s3.putObject(params).promise();
```

Is there a way to do what I'm thinking?

Obs: 'body' is a array and its average number of records is 10.000 or even more.